# ¿Cómo escribir código en Golang correctamente?

Tags: go

Me ha surgido esa duda después de estar leyendo Effective-Go y la documentación de golang.org. Para practicar lo que había leído he hecho el siguiente código que me he genera un par de dudas sobre eficiencia y escritura de código en go:

```
package main

import(
        "log"
        "strconv"
        "fmt"
        "github.com/levigross/grequests"
)

type Credentials struct {
        url, usr, tkn string
}

//Set the credentials to a client
func (c *Credentials) setCredentials(url, usr, tkn string) {
        c.url = url
        c.usr = usr
        c.tkn = tkn
}


func showTicket(subdomain, usr, tkn string, id int) string {
        s := strconv.Itoa(id)
        usrTkn := fmt.Sprintf("%s/token", usr)
        ro := &grequests.RequestOptions{Auth: []string{usrTkn, tkn}}
        path := fmt.Sprintf("/api/v2/tickets/%s.json", s)
        url := fmt.Sprintf("%s%s", subdomain, path)
        resp, err :=  grequests.Get(url, ro)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalln("Unable to make request: ", err)
        }
        return resp.String()
}

func main() {
        url := "http://url.com"
        usr := "test"
        tkn := "1234token"
        client := new(Credentials) // returns a pointer to Credentials
        client.setCredentials(url, usr, tkn)
        id := 1
        ticket := showTicket(client.url, client.usr, client.tkn, id)
        fmt.Println(ticket)
}
```

Mis dudas son:

la función setCredentials debería estar en una interface? He leído que las interfaces recogen estados, pero no me queda claro si realmente esto es una función o un estado.

A la hora de concatenar strings, uso el método Sprintf de fmt, pero también he leído que para cosas así es más recomendable usar io.Reader o io.Writer, y no entiendo el por qué, si es por el tema de que ambas trabajan con []bytes o porque son más rápidas, ...

showTicket también no sabría si ponerlo en una interface que fuese Ticket o solo es una función más.

Tengo un problema de comprensión entre cuando usar una interface, una función o usar un método de un struct.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la mejor forma que tienes de aprender cuando utilizar cada cosa es la biblioteca estándar del lenguaje.

Usas interfaces cuando estás creando funcionalidades genéricas que dependen de que ciertos tipos se comporten (por comportar quiero decir, tener métodos) de cierta forma. `io.Reader` e `io.Writer` son el ejemplo más sencillo y uno de los más utilizados. Te pongo el ejemplo de `io.Copy`:

```
func Copy(dst Writer, src Reader) (written int64, err error) {
    return copyBuffer(dst, src, nil)
}
```

Esta función espera un `Writer` y un `Reader`, es decir tipos que tengan una función (método):

```
 Write(p []byte) (n int, err error)
```

o

```
Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)
```

Ahora si tu quieres utilizar `io.Copy` en tu tipo `BananaWriter` nada más tienes que:

```
func (self BananaWriter*) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error)
```

Un `struct` lo utilizas ya para representar tipos de datos  en concreto (`BananaWriter` por ejemplo). Piensa en "objetos" de los lenguajes comunes (C++,Java,C#, etc).